# How to resolve unittest ImportErrors

Tags: python, importerror, python-unittest

When I run:

`python -m unittest discover unit_tests`

or

`python setup.py test`

I receive lots of `ImportErrors` for the [blowdrycss project](https://github.com/nueverest/blowdrycss).

Sample:

```
test_BreakpointParser (unittest.loader._FailedTest) ... ERROR
test_classExtractor (unittest.loader._FailedTest) ... ERROR
test_classPropertyParser (unittest.loader._FailedTest) ... ERROR
test_colorParser (unittest.loader._FailedTest) ... ERROR
test_CSSBuilder (unittest.loader._FailedTest) ... ERROR
test_CSSFile (unittest.loader._FailedTest) ... ERROR
test_CSSPropertyValueParser (unittest.loader._FailedTest) ... ERROR
...
ImportError: No module named 'settings'
ImportError: No module named 'blowdrycss_settings'
ImportError: No module named 'blowdrycss.blowdrycss_settings'
ImportError: No module named 'utilities'
ImportError: No module named 'breakpointparser'
```

Project structure:

```
blowdrycss/
    blowdrycss/
        settings/
            __init__.py
            blowdrycss_settings.py
        unit_tests/
            __init__.py
            test_BreakpointParser.py
            test_*.py
            ...
        __init__.py
        blowdrycss.py
        breakpointparser.py
        utilities.py
        ...
```

What is strange is that when I run these tests from PyCharm everything passes, but when I run from the command line it breaks.

Maybe it is a simple configuration issue, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

How do I resolve these ImportErrors?

Answer (score 8):

There were multiple issues.

The primary issue was that `blowdrycss.py` was the same name as the package.  This caused the python importer to be confused.

Changing the name of `blowdrycss.py` to `blowdry.py` helped.

The other half of the problem was the the current working directory was not being added to the `PYTHONPATH`.  I fixed this by adding the following lines to `__init__.py`:

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
sys.path.insert(0, cwd)
```